# $F_n \overset{w}{\to} F$, and $F$ is continous. Show that $F_n$ converges to $F$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> $\{F_n\}$ and $F$ are distribution functions, and $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. If $F_n$ converges weakly to $F$, show that 
>   $$
> \sup_x | F_n(x) - F(x) | \to 0, n \to \infty
> $$

I know that weak convergence is equivalent to the condition that $F_n$ converges to $F$ at every continuity of $F$, but how to show the uniform convergence here? Much appreciation to any help!

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1285958/

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following strategy:

- first show that if $t_n\to t$, then 
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|F_n(t_n)-F_n(t)|=0.$$
  You will need to use the weak convergence of $F_n(t)$ to $F(t)$ and the fact that $F_n$ is non-decreasing.
- second, fix a positive $\varepsilon$, reduce the uniform convergence on the real line to a uniform convergence on a compact interval and argue by contradiction.

Comment: Can you give a few more details?

Comment: I can, but you may want to precise which step I have to detail.

Comment: Thank you Davide Giraudo! But you need not explain. I found that one other question where you answer a similar question with all the details. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467976/uniform-convergence-and-weak-convergence

Comment: If you have not forgotten this, could you give me more details on the each of rist and second strategy?