# Central limit theorem as pointwise convergence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I stumbled accross this in my lecture notes and I am not sure why this is true? Let $S_n$ be the sum of $n$ i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \leq \sqrt{15}x + \frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{n}}x^2 \right) \to \mathbb{P}(Z\leq \sqrt{15}x) = \Phi(\sqrt{15}x)
$$
I know that $\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{n}}x^2 \to 0 $. However, central limit theorem states that $\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \leq x) \to \mathbb{P}(Z\leq x)$ converges pointwise. I am not sure then why the above expression is true? In general, if $x_n\to x$ is it true that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \leq x_n) \to \mathbb{P}(Z \leq x) = \Phi(x)?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand this, this uses two results.

Define $F(x) = P(Z \leq x)$ and $F_n(x) = P(Z_n \leq x)$.

> If $F$ is continuous (which is the case when $Z \sim N(0,1))$ and $Z_n
>  \stackrel{d}\to Z$, then we have $F_n \to F$ uniformly, i.e. $\sup_{x
>  \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)- F(x) | \to 0$.

Now, use the following lemma:

> If $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $x_n \to x$, then $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: Are $Z_n$ standard normal variables?

Comment: Not necessarily. Anything that converges in distribution to $Z$.

Comment: Where do you get the first result from?

Comment: See for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285958/weak-convergence-in-probability-implies-uniform-convergence-in-distribution-func