# A doubt about the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I have a doubt about the central limit theorem.

Let $(X_n)$ be an IID sequence, each $X_n$ distributed as $X$ where

$\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, $\sigma^2 = Var(X) < \infty$.

Define $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, and set

$G_n = \frac{S_n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}$

Now, the theorem tells us that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(G_n \le x) = \Phi(x)$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Now is it FORMALLY correct to say, for example, that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(G_n \le 1+\frac{1}{n}) = \Phi(\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})) = \Phi(1) \simeq 0.8413$?

Thanks to who will solve my (perhaps trivial) doubt.

Comment: No: $x$ is a number, not a function of $n$.

Comment: In this case, how can I estimate that probability?

Comment: The CLT is merely telling you how to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(G_n \leq x)$ for fixed $x$ not depending on $n$. You might hope by some interchange of limits result or similar that you can replace $x$ by a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ but that's not the same result.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you mean "not a function of $n$" instead - $x$ certainly is a function of $x$ ;)

Comment: LJG: You accepted instantly the answer below. As a consequence your question basically disappeared from the list of those to answer, which made that you are left with the unique answer below. Too bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not formally correct because $1+1/n$ is a sequence of numbers which depends on $n$, whereas the CLT as stated only holds for fixed real numbers $x$.

However, it is still true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(G_n \leq 1+1/n) = \Phi(1)$. In order to prove this, one only needs to use the fact that the functions $F_n(x):=P(G_n \leq x)$ are increasing, together with continuity of the limit $\Phi$. Indeed, for $N \leq n$, one has that $F_n(1+1/n) \leq F_n(1+1/N)$, and thus for any fixed $N$ $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}F_n(1+1/n) \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} F_n(1+1/N) = \Phi(1+1/N)$$ Next, we may let $N \to \infty$ on both sides, and since the LHS does not depend on $N$, one sees by continuity of $\Phi$ that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}F_n(1+1/n) \leq \lim_{N\to \infty} \Phi(1+1/N) = \Phi(1)$$ 
On the other hand, one clearly has that $F_n(1+1/n) \geq F_n(1)$ fo every $n$, and therefore we see that $$\liminf_{N \to \infty} F_n(1+1/n) \geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} F_n(1) = \Phi(1)$$ which (together with the preceding expression) gives the desired result.

In fact, because of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467976/uniform-convergence-and-weak-convergence), it is actually true that one has *uniform convergence* of the cdf's $F_n$ to $\Phi$, which means that $F_n(x_n) \to \Phi(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$ (and the proof uses the same ideas).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you give me some advice to estimate in a formal way that probability?

Comment: We did not study Berry–Esseen theorem. Anyway, for the theorem you talked about before, can I write safely that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(G_n \le 1+\frac{1}{n}) =  \Phi(1)$?

Comment: @LJG Yes, see the linked question

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.

Comment: Uniform convergence is not needed, only monotonicity of the functions and continuity of the limiting function are.

Comment: @Did You are correct, it was a lazy answer. I have edited my answer and I hope that it fits your standards better. Thank you for your quality check.

Comment: @LJG As Did points out, my previous answer was incomplete, thus I suggest you take a look at the argument which I edited in.

Comment: @Did Maybe I accepted the answer too soon, but I am a new user and I still have to understand the best way to use this platform.

Comment: @Shalop I've seen the changes and thank you for the further clarification.

Comment: @LJG "The best way to use the platform" is to read the answers one gets, before accepting them. You accepted this post 30 minutes after it was posted. Do you think this delay was sufficient for you to fully check the validity of the post?

Comment: @Shalop Your answer is now correct (and gives the standard proof)... until the last paragraph, which I still do not understand. The exact same proof that you gave for $1+\frac1n$ actually shows that $$\lim F_n(x_n)=\Phi(x)$$ for **every** sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$, no?

Comment: @Did The same proof will work for _monotone_ sequences converging to $x\;( =1$ in this case $)$, and for general convergent sequences the result may then be deduced. That's what I was trying to say in the last paragraph.